# Can ngnix server check for multiple params in the url making them serve same file?

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-location

Since both of the below 'if statements' serve the same type of file but check for different parameters in the URL, like the first one checks for 'flag1' and the second one checks for 'flag2', I want to merge both of these checks into just one 'if statement' serving that file:

```
location /app/ {
    location ~ "^(.*)/([^/]+)_flag\.(.*)$" {
        try_files $uri $1/$2.$3 =404;
    }

    if ( $args ~ "^.*flag1.*$" ) {
        rewrite ^(.*)/([^/]+(?<!_flag))\.(.*)$ $1/$2_flag.$3 last;
    }

    if ( $args ~ "^.*flag2.*$" ) {
        rewrite ^(.*)/([^/]+(?<!_flag))\.(.*)$ $1/$2_flag.$3 last;
    }
}
```

Can this be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. You should use `or` condition:

```
if ( $args ~ "(^.*flag1.*$)|(^.*flag2.*$)" )
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I tried for "^.*flag1.*$|^.*flag2.*$" and even "^.*flag1|flag2.*$" but it wasn't working. I guess I was wrong.